# How to Convert https://tangrams.github.io/heightmapper coordinates to decimal latitude longitude

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, conversion

[image]

how to convert This:
9.70833/36.7798/-478.5508
to
decimal latitude longitude to see this location on google maps

https://tangrams.github.io/heightmapper/#9.70833/36.7798/-478.5508

my first question on this site
please help

Comment: You can generally convert github.io sites to github.com sites with more information. In this case, https://github.com/tangrams may be helpful

Comment: Is that a real heightmapper url? When I tested heightmapper the url was in the format `https://tangrams.github.io/heightmapper/#zoomlevel/latitude/longitude`. When I paste your example it doesn't take me anywhere, and the last value (-470.020) doesn't make sense as a longitude.